# How to throttle a producer in a producer/consumer situation on a TChan in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

We have something dumping values on a TChan, and then a consumer processing those. But the consumer can't keep up, so we're getting lots of memory usage as the producer is dumping lots of stuff on the channel, but consumer isn't keeping up. Is there a straightforward way to have the producer block if the channel queue becomes a certain size or something so we can have the producer wait for the consumer to catch up?

Comment: First search result for "bounded tchan": [github/jnb/bounded-tchan](https://github.com/jnb/bounded-tchan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like John's answer, I'd suggest just building a bounded TChan yourself.  My code is different because it:

1. adds abstraction (makes `BTChan` an ADT)
2. removes the corner case due to his reading the current size in IO.
3. tries not to build thunks in the size TVar when reading (it's less important when writing because the thunk can only be "one deep" - the next operation always needs to evaluate the size).
4. is now on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bounded-tchan

NOTE: Honestly, if I were you I'd ignore all these answers and just go with the code ephemient linked to in his comment (unless it turns out to be bad code).  I'd bet it does the same I do here but with more thought.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module BTChan
        ( BTChan
        , newBTChanIO
        , newBTChan
        , writeBTChan
        , readBTChan
        ) where

import Control.Concurrent.STM

data BTChan a = BTChan {-# UNPACK #-} !Int (TChan a) (TVar  Int)

-- | `newBTChan m` make a new bounded TChan of max size `m`
newBTChanIO :: Int -> IO (BTChan a)
newBTChanIO m = do
    szTV <- newTVarIO 0
    c    <- newTChanIO
    return (BTChan m c szTV)

newBTChan :: Int -> STM (BTChan a)
newBTChan m 
        | m < 1 = error "BTChan's can not have a maximum <= 0!"
        | otherwise = do
        szTV <- newTVar 0
        c    <- newTChan
        return (BTChan m c szTV)

writeBTChan :: BTChan a -> a -> STM ()
writeBTChan (BTChan mx c szTV) x = do
        sz <- readTVar szTV
        if sz >= mx then retry else writeTVar szTV (sz + 1) >> writeTChan c x

readBTChan :: BTChan a -> STM a
readBTChan (BTChan _ c szTV) = do
        x <- readTChan c
        sz <- readTVar szTV
        let !sz' = sz - 1
        writeTVar szTV sz'
        return x

sizeOfBTChan :: BTChan a -> STM Int
sizeOfBTChan (BTChan _ _ sTV) = readTVar sTV
```

Some things of note for the STM programmer:

- Explicitly calling `retry` will yield, putting your haskell thread in a blocked state waiting for the state of one of the `TVar` or `TChan` to change so it can retry.  This is how you avoid checking values in `IO` and using the `yield` function.
- Like MVars, TVars can refer to thunks, which usually isn't what you want.  Perhaps someone should make a hackage package defining `STVar`, `STChan`, `SBTChan` and `BTChan` (Strict and/or bounded TVars and TChans).
- It is actually necessary to write `newBTChanIO` instead of leverage `newBTChan` because the implementations of `new{TVar,TChan}IO` are made to work even when under `unsafePerformIO`, which `atomically` can not do.

EDIT: you can actually get 2-5 times better performance (depending on the bound you use) by separating out the TVar into one for the reader and one for the writer, thus reducing contention.  Verified using criterion.  The improved version, 0.2.1, is already on hackage.

Comment: do you have a reference that explicitly calling `retry` will always yield?

Comment: @John  it doesn't always yeild, but it won't retry till one of the TVar's it read are rewritten, meaning it won't retry when the value is unchanged which would result in the same `retry` getting called again.  SimonPJ has links to some very readable [STM papers](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/stm/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest solution is to add a `TVar` indicating the number of elements in the channel:

```
type BoundedChan a = (TChan a, TVar Int, Int)

writeBoundedChan :: BoundedChan a -> a -> IO ()
writeBoundedChan bc@(tchan, tsz, maxsz) x = do
  cursz' <- readTVarIO tsz
  if cursz' >= maxsz
    then yield >> writeBoundedChan bc x
    else atomically $ do
      writeTChan tchan a
      cursz <- readTVar tsz
      writeTVar tsz (cursz+1)

readBoundedChan :: BoundedChan a -> IO a
readBoundedChan (tchan, tsz, maxsz) = atomically $ do
  x <- readTChan tchan
  cursz <- readTVar tsz
  writeTVar tsz (cursz-1)
  return x
```

Note that the max size can be slightly exceeded if you have multiple producers, because the cursz value can change between the two reads.

Comment: You don't need to check the `cursz` in IO before the atomically.  Just do it all in atomically in one read: `readTVar >>= \cursz -> if cursz >= maxsz then retry else ...`  Notice the use of `retry` there.

Comment: @TomMD - if you `retry` within the same `STM` block, the thread won't necessarily yield.  The hackage docs say it "may block the thread", so I wouldn't assume that it always will block.  I also wouldn't trust that the behavior won't change in future implementations.  I might just be paranoid, because I can't see why a non-blocking retry would be useful, but that's my take.

Comment: Yielding is how `retry` works, it does not run the same STM operation on the same, unchanged, TVars.  It "may" yield because it does not yeild if the TVars were changed by another STM operation concurrent with the `retry`ing one.  If you're still uncomfortable with this then you can have `writeBoundedChan` call an `STM` operation that returns `Bool` and `yeild`s when `False`, returns when `True` - that should work OK (wastes more processing power than `retry`  due to remaining a schedule-able thread) and remove the size-exceeded bug.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late to the game, but you could alternatively implement a *Skip Channel*, which allows non-blocking writes to the channel, but "overwrites" the old value that has not been seen by any reader.

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

data SkipChan a = SkipChan (MVar (a, [MVar ()])) (MVar ())

newSkipChan :: IO (SkipChan a)
newSkipChan = do
    sem <- newEmptyMVar
    main <- newMVar (undefined, [sem])
    return (SkipChan main sem)

putSkipChan :: SkipChan a -> a -> IO ()
putSkipChan (SkipChan main _) v = do
    (_, sems) <- takeMVar main
    putMVar main (v, [])
    mapM_ (\sem -> putMVar sem ()) sems

getSkipChan :: SkipChan a -> IO a
getSkipChan (SkipChan main sem) = do
    takeMVar sem
    (v, sems) <- takeMVar main
    putMVar main (v, sem:sems)
    return v

dupSkipChan :: SkipChan a -> IO (SkipChan a)
dupSkipChan (SkipChan main _) = do
    sem <- newEmptyMVar
    (v, sems) <- takeMVar main
    putMVar main (v, sem:sems)
    return (SkipChan main sem)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [BoundedChan](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/BoundedChan) on hackage, but that uses MVars, not STM.  You could use it to learn how to write your own - it is only about a page of code.